# What is the effect of the compact extra dimensions of the heterotic theories?

Tags: string-theory, compactification

The five super-string theories are generally said to be 10-dimensional. However the Heterotic theories combine a bosonic left mover (which lives in 26 dimensions) with a super right mover (which lives in 10 dimensions). The extra 16 dimensions compactify into a torus with either $\frac{\operatorname{Spin}32}{\mathbb Z_ 2}$ or $E_8\times E_8$ symmetry.

So these theories differ from the others by this compact torus.

What is the effect of the this torus physically?

Comment: You mean extra 16?

Comment: Simply, it gives the string theories different gauge groups (so clearly, different physical meaning, even though the actions are the same, heterotic action)

Comment: @prahar:yes - obviously forgotten arithmetic.